# CFINPUT - How to exclude O, o, I, i from input value

Tags: coldfusion

How can I force format in Coldfusion for alphanumeric characters to exclude O, o, I, i? Mask apparently doesn't work.

**Update from comments:**
The following example is how to force a format with characters and numbers, but it allows O & I. I would like to exclude these two.

```
<cfinput type="text" name="newPart" mask="EB-9999-XX-999999" />
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is very ambiguous. Please post a *self-contained* example showing what code you have tried. Be sure to include an explanation of how the results differ from what you expected.

Comment: Excluding certain characters probably means that you will have to use regular expressions.  That takes mask out of the equation.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Dan Bracuk!

Answer (score 0):

Leigh and Dan are both correct. More info is needed, and you'll ultimately likely end up with some RegEx.

What is the end goal? Do you want to keep users from entering any character that looks like a zero or a one (my assumption)? That should probably also include L. What about 0 and 1 themselves? Do you want to change these characters as they are entered into a form field or after they are submitted by the form? If you mask them before submission, how will you let the user know they're submitting something different than what they're entering?

Based on my assumptions above, you could start with replacing them in the form field itself with Javascript.

```
<input name="formStr" type='text' 
    onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.replace(/o/ig,'0')
        .replace(/l|i/ig,'1').replace(/[^0-9a-z]/ig,'')
    ">
```

Then also replace the entry before you do anything with it. I've always been a fan of using the Java String functions for string manipulation. It's very fast.

```
inStr = FORM.formStr.replaceAll("(?i)[o]","0")
        .replaceAll("(?i)[il]","1")
        .replaceAll("(?i)[^0-9a-z]","")
    ;
```

You don't want to just do the masking in the form field. Someone can still Right-Click >> Paste into that field and submit the form with invalid characters. Ctrl-V pasting does involve an onKeyUp event, so the text will get masked that way, but the Java replaceAll() takes care of it on the submission end.

Or if replacing all of the above characters with an empty string:

```
onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9a-hjkmnp-z]/ig,'')"
```

and

```
inStr2 = FORM.formStr.replaceAll("(?i)[^0-9a-hjkmnp-z]","");
```

But again, without knowing more about how this input will be used, it's hard to give accurate help.

NOTE: The onKeyUp worked in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox. Odd. It's been a while since I've written JS and I haven't dug too deeply into this one, so I don't know what I missed to make it fail. Perhaps someone else can shed light.

And an added FYI: Ben Nadel has a bunch of excellent information about using RegEx. And plenty of other sources. It's worth checking out.

Comment: Bah! Apparently I don't use Firefox on that VM very often. It was embarrassingly out of date. Patched up to latest version and my JS works. I hate problems like that. :-S

Comment: Thanks Shawn, the goal is to keep users away from using these two letters I and O. Doing so assume using 0 and 1 is ok. And when the data is entered in lower case, after refreshing should be in upper case.

Comment: I'd be careful. I think you might be setting yourself up for a whole bunch of user questions and complaints. If this is for a password-type field, I'd just let them enter what they want. Nobody else should be able to read it anyway. If not, it still might be better to let them enter what they want. But user validation like this can quickly become a major headache with significantly reduced returns on effort. It all depends on how the input will be used in the output.

Comment: Funny enough, I just came across this issue at lunch. Don't forget about 2 and z. The 0-oO and 1-IilL issues show up easily in data display, but writing them out also pops 2 and Z.

Comment: Yes, I was testing onKeyUp line, which worked the best for my case, but you're right, the users have no idea what's wrong before they see an error message which appears after they try to submit. At that point the error message works fine. I'm just wondering if I could make an error message appears at the moment user type one of the restricted characters.